# Nunit Moq: Unsupported expression: Value Non-overridable members may not be used in setup / verification expressions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I writing unit test for a function and for that I need to mock an entity. This is how I'm trying to mock:

```cs
Mock<ISimpleData> data = new Mock<ISimpleData>();
data.Setup(i => i.RiskId.Value).Returns("123");//gets error here
```

`RiskId` is of type `StringData : DataGeneric<string>`. From the error, it appears that Moq dll is unable to fetch `RiskId.Value` because of the data type of `RiskId`.

Is there any way I can still mock `RiskId.Value` attribute as this is being used in the function for which I'm writing the test. Following is the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: ... => ....Value
> Non-overridable members (here: DataGeneric.get_Value) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
> at Moq.Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression expression) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Guard.cs:line 99
> at Moq.InvocationShape..ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList'1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments, Boolean skipMatcherInitialization, Boolean allowNonOverridable) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\InvocationShape.cs:line 84
> at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r, InvocationShape& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 324
> at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 149
> at Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 505
> at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression'1 expression) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock'1.cs:line 454
> System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unaware of any built-in `DataGeneric` class, so I assume it is a user-defined class.

The error says

> ... Value Non-overridable members (here: DataGeneric.get_Value) ...

which means you should not mock the `RiskId.Value`.

You should try to setup a mock for the `RiskId` itself:

```
data.Setup(i => i.RiskId).Returns(new StringData("123"));
```

I've assumed your `StringData` has a constructor which can receive its value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could implement your own implementation of `ISimpleData` like this:

```cs
public class MyTests
{
    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var data = new SimpleDataMock("123");

        // Act
        // ...

        // Assert
        // ...
    }

    private class SimpleDataMock : ISimpleData
    {
        public SimpleDataMock(string riskValue) => this.RiskId.Value = riskValue;

        // ...
    }
}
```